# Ajax with HighCharts setData on Symfony 2

Tags: php, json, ajax, symfony, highcharts

I have a problem on my HighCharts graph with JSON data. To explain a litle bit : I have a form, when I submit this form I send my data to my controller with Ajax, I treat them and I return the new array of data for my highcharts graph, but when I use `setData` function with my new array the graph disappear and the new data aren't displayed.

Here is my ajax function and my test to set the new data into my graph :

```
$('#gestion .l-gestion-content-form #form-add-informations .btn-validation').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var chart = $('#hightchart-graf').highcharts();
    var dataActionForm = $('#form-add-informations').attr('action').split("/");
    var url_ajax = Routing.generate('gestion_view', { dossier: dataActionForm[4], fille: dataActionForm[5] });
    var formData = $('#form-add-informations').serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url:  url_ajax,
        data: formData,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            console.log(msg['infosArray']);
            var test = [ msg['infosArray'].join(',') ];
            console.log(test);
            console.log('---------------------------------------------');
            console.log(msg.infosArray);
            var test2 = msg.infosArray.join(',');
            var test3 = test2.replace('"', '');
            console.log(test2);

            chart.series[0].setData( [ msg.infosArray.join(',') ] );

            //[ {{ msg.infosArray | join(',') }} ]
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    });
});
```

All my data are stored in the array named `msg.infosArray` or `msg['infosArray']` and the first `console.log` return an array like this :

```
["[Date.UTC(2015,11,23),80.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,23),89.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,25),150.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,28),45.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,29),169.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,29),189.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,29),196.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,29),200.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,29),205.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,30),210.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,31),225.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,1),250.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,2),25.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,3),259.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,5),25.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,6),250.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,7),25.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,8),250.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,9),25.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,10),250.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,11),25.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,12),250.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,25),25.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,26),250.00]"]
```

So I tried to escape `"` and `'` or to join the array but nothing work. Somebody know how can I set the new data, or where I commited a fault ?
Maybe i got a bad response from my Controller ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you send an array of strings, instead of validate json. Morever Date.UTC() cannot excecute when you remove brackets etc. So you should create native json with timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string of `javascript` code to array of javascript.

I wrote a demo version which converts string to javascript code. and draws chart as expected. Do not focus on the labels it's a dummy data.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/90uzfhzw/1/)

```
    $(function () {
  var data = ["[Date.UTC(2015,11,23),80.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,23),89.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,25),150.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,28),45.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,29),169.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,29),189.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,29),196.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,29),200.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,29),205.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,30),210.00]", "[Date.UTC(2015,11,31),225.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,1),250.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,2),25.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,3),259.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,5),25.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,6),250.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,7),25.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,8),250.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,9),25.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,10),250.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,11),25.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,12),250.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,25),25.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,0,26),250.00]"];
  //t = t.map(function(element){return eval(element);});
  data = data.map(function (e) {
    return eval(e);
  });
  data = data.map(function (e) {
    return [(new Date(e[0])).toLocaleString(), e[1]]
  });
  var categories = data.map(function (e) {
    return (new Date(e[0])).toLocaleString()
  });
  // t[0] = [date = new Date(t[0])];
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
      x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
      x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: categories
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }]
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Tokyo',
      data: data
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, The solution was to use `eval` function like this : `var test = eval("[" + msg['infosArray'] + "]");` and `chart.series[0].setData(test);`. Thanks for the help !